# Run a Python Script from the Web

Tags: python, web-services, web-applications, web, python-2.7

I've been stumbling along with the same problem for almost a year now. I always find a way to work around it, but I'm tired of finding work arounds.

What I need is to create a button on a Web Page (preferable HTML, not PHP or ASP) that runs a python script on the server. I'd also like the ability to have this button send information from a form to the script.

I need to do this on a local host and through a web service hosted on the Amazon Cloud. I won't be able to install anything extra on the Amazon Cloud service, such as PHP or CGI.

I'd really like an easy solution, I'm an expert with python and I can write webpages that whistle, but I just can't find a simple solution to this problem.

My ideal solution would be something like the mail to tag:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello%20again">Send Mail</a>
```

Except:

```
<a href="myscript.py?Subject=1234">Run Script</a>
```

Now I highly doubt a solution like that exists, but well I can dream right.

The script I am trying to run:

1. Returns a Unique ID from the user
2. Sends the ID to a GIS program that creates a map based on the ID (the ID selects the area of the map)
3. The map is then exported to a PNG, wrote into an HTML document and then displayed for the user in a new tab.

EDIT ---------------------------

Thanks to @Ketouem answer I was able to find a great solution to my issue. I'll post some of the code here so that others can benefit. Make sure you download the Bottle Module for python, its great.

```
# 01 - Import System Modules
from bottle import get, post, request, Bottle, run, template

# 02 - Script Variables
app = Bottle()

# 03 - Build Temporary Webpage
@app.route('/SLR')
def login_form():
    return '''<form method="POST" action="/SLR">
                Parcel Fabric ID: <input name="UID" type="text" /><br />
                Save Location: <input name="SaveLocation" type="text" value="D:/Python27/BottleTest/SLR_TestOutputs"/><br />
                Air Photo On: <input name="AirPhoto" type="checkbox"/><br />                
                Open on Completion: <input name="Open" type="checkbox"/><br />
                Scale: <input name="Scale" type="text" value="10000"/><br />
                <input type="submit" />
              </form>'''

# 04 - Return to GIS App
@app.route('/SLR', method='POST')
def PHPH_SLR_Script():
    # I won't bother adding the GIS Section of the code, but at this point it send the variables to a program that makes a map. This map then saves as an XML and opens up in a new tab.

 # 04 - Create and Run Page
run(app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: can you run a daemon using web.py, flask or pyramid ?

Comment: I've had another issue on the problem, if anyone can help it is located [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010556/python-bottle-issues-when-accessed-externally)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use Bottle : http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html which is a light web framework

Comment: Hmm, this is a pretty interesting solution, I'm going to have to experiment with it before I really know if it'll work for my situation though.

Comment: Fantastic Solution, I'll add my code to my answer, but you really helped with this module suggestion.

Comment: @CodyBrown your solution?