# Python Bottle Issues when Accessed Externally

Tags: python, html, port, bottle

So I am using the bottle module for python to listen for requests on my server. I've done all the testing locally and now that it has come time for deployment, I can't get it to run on my server.

```
from bottle import route, get, post, request, Bottle, run, template

@route('/Request/<UniqueID>') #Build Temporary Webpage
def login_form(UniqueID):
    return '''<form method="POST" action="/SLR_Creation">
                ID: <input name="UID" type="text" value="''' +UniqueID+ '''" /><br />
                Scale: <input name="Scale" type="text" value="10000"/><br />
                <input type="submit" value="CLick here to create report"/>
              </form>'''

@route('/<UniqueID>', method='POST') # Return
def PHPH_Script(UniqueID):
     # Big long script to create a report
     return '''<p>The report has been created. Click this button to access it.<br /></p>
            <form action="''' + WebLocation +'''.html">
                <input type="submit" value="CLick here to access report">
            </form>'''    

# Create and Run Page
#run(host='localhost', port=8080)
run(host='12.34.255.89', port=80) # This is not my actually IP Address.
```

Now that last line of code is what keeps giving me an error of: **error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context.** Now if I use the commented out line, it works like a charm.

I know that my IP is correct and the port is open, so does anyone have any idea of what my issue is here?

Comment: In the host the dot separated numbers are `0 - 255` and low port numbers are controled by the OS.

Comment: Sorry, that's just a fake IP address, I forgot about the max of 255 for IP's. The port is open, I can confirm that through other means.

Comment: You can bind to port 80 if you have root privileges AND nothing else is running on port 80.  You may have apache/nginx/or something else running on that already.  Only one service can bind to a port at a given time.  Try running it on 8080 or similar as suggested by @fp

Comment: most people will also run stuff like this listening on 0.0.0.0 ; that will listen on any ips.

Comment: So the 0.0.0.0 actually starts listening and does not give an error, but when I go to the page: 'http://domain.com/Request/1' I get an 404 page not found error

Comment: You have to put the port on the client side: `http://12.34.255.89:8080/Request/<UniqueID>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe several issues:

1. port 80 may be in use by another task, even if it crashed.
2. If you use say port 8080 you have to use

   `http://12.34.255.89:8080/Request/...`
3. `method='POST'` can run into protection issues and be unreliable in some cases.
4. See that the route matches including things like `.html`

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter which port I use, when using the server IP is always comes back with the same error. When I use port 0.0.0.0 it does actually listen, but when I try to access the site, I get a 404 error.